# How do i clear the stdcout, or cancel a pipe in c?

Tags: c, pipe

i have a parser that generates c code and prints it using `printf` and i want to pipe it like this:

```
./program | gcc -xc -
```

The problem is that if i encounter an error i need to pipe nothing to gcc.
Is there a better solution then parsing once to scan for errors and then parsing to print the output to stdout?

Comment: I would recommend not using the pipe at all. Instead `if ./program > out.c; then gcc out.c; fi` (or `./program > out.c && gcc out.c`) This assumes your `program` has rational exit values.

Comment: Or simply generate some bogus C that will fail to compile.  But that is not as clean as “generate the C file and only compile it if the generation was successful”.  Only pipe to the compiler if you are sure you aren't going to have problems generating the code to be compiled.

Comment: What about `stderr`?